# "C^0 estimate for solutions to $\Delta(u)+e^{-u} \geq 0$"

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}.$ Suppose I have a solution to the equation

$$\Delta(u)+e^{-u} \geq 0$$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let r be the radial coordinate on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that $$lim_{r \to \infty} u \to c$$

where $c$ is some constant. Can I get some estimate on the maximum of $u$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? I'm sorry if my question admits an easy solution, but I am not usually working on analysis and couldn't find this precise situation in the literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One cannot bound $\sup u$ in terms of $c$.** To see this, set $u(x) = c + \alpha \,\varphi(\varepsilon x)$, where $\varphi\in S(\mathbb R^2;\mathbb R)$, $\varphi(0)=1$, and $\varphi\leq1$, while $\alpha>0$, $\varepsilon>0$ are parameters. Notice that
$$
  \Delta u(x) + e^{-u(x)} \geq  e^{-\alpha} \left( e^\alpha\alpha\varepsilon^2 
  \inf\Delta\varphi + e^{-c} \right).
$$

Now, given $K>c_+$, let $\alpha=K-c>0$ and choose $\varepsilon>0$ in
such a way that $e^\alpha\alpha\varepsilon^2 \inf\Delta\varphi +
e^{-c}\geq0$. Then $\sup u= u(0)=K$ and $\Delta u + e^{-u}\geq0$;
so we have the desired example.

Answer (score 7):

According to J. Liouville *Sur l'équation aux différences partielles* $\partial^2\log\lambda/\partial u\partial v\pm\lambda/2a^2$ **J. Maths. Pures & Appl. 18** (1853), pp 71-71, the general solution of this equation in the plane is given by the formula
$$u=-\log\frac{8|f'(z)|^2}{(1-|f(z)|^2)^2}\,,$$where $f$ is holomorphic. You should start from that.

If a solution $u$ exists in the whole plane, it seems that $f$ must be a bounded entire function, hence a constant, from which it follows $u\equiv0$. Perhaps this can be proved by Pohozaev's calculus.

You can also use the paper by H. Fujita **Bull. AMS 75** (1969), pp 132-135, which treats the equation in arbitrary space dimension.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but perhaps I am not understanding the following. Your answer treats the case of $\Delta(u)=-e^{-u}$,correct? What does this imply about the above inequality(other than being a special case)?

Comment: This is not a special case. All the solutions $u$ are given by this formula, for a suitable holomorphic function $f$.